# How to send user entered value on submitting with minimum validation or required error in angular js

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

Here we were trying to send the user entered input value to Servlet.

So below is one example, When user entered minimum length for input field then inbuilt angular validation occurs and because of this minimum length validation error its **related field model value** is set to **"undefined"** or **empty**.

Due to this in the servlet we are getting the value as empty. Unable to do Server side validation.

Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-text-input-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="textInputExample">
   <script>
   angular.module('textInputExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.text = 'guest';
       $scope.word = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;
     }]);
 </script>
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   Single word: <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="text"
                       ng-pattern="word" ng-minlength="4" ng-trim="false">
   <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
     Required!</span>
   <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.minlength">
     Single word only!</span>

   <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>Modal Text Box Value = {{text}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dig down and retrieve the `$viewValue` from `$scope.myForm`. I can't comment on if this is a best practice, but it will certainly give you the value you are looking for, despite the form being invalid. Hope this helps.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-text-input-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="textInputExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('textInputExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.text = 'guest';
          $scope.word = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;

          $scope.submitForm = function() {
            console.log($scope.myForm.input.$viewValue);
            console.log($scope.text);
          }
        }
      ]);
  </script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    Single word:
    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="text" ng-pattern="word" ng-minlength="4" ng-trim="false">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
     Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.minlength">
     Single word only!</span>
    <br>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt>
    <br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt>
    <br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt>
    <br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt>
    <br/>
    <tt>Modal Text Box Value = {{text}}</tt>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But my scenario is like even though we have error in form fields the submission should happen and value entered should pass to servlet. The thing is when $error is true then angular making the modal as empty or undefined. But I want the exact value entered by the user to be passed. Did you come across any of this scenario ?

Comment: @Visagan You still haven't explained why you want that. It makes no sense to me. You know in advance that the servlet will (or at least should) reject the submit, but you still choose to do it. Why? What's the point?

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think will achieve your results.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Yes I agree, the servlet will reject the submit. But thats my client requirement :) .... Might be my client thinks this process will make the app security stronger ;)

Comment: @TrazeK : Hey thanks, Im able to get the user entered value. Really appreciate Your timely help !

Comment: Talk to your client. Try to understand why they want that. Explain them that their app will be faster and consume less bandwidth and CPU if the submission is prevented.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thanks a lot for your suggestions ! .. We already had a discussion with them. Nothing had worked out. But will try to have one more time with some of your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting ng-pattern, required, ng-minlength, etc. on your form, that means that you want to perform validation at client side. So you simply shouldn't allow the user to send a request to your servlet while the form is invalid. The easiest and simplest way being to disable the submit button if the form is invalid:

```
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ...
```

That doesn't mean, of course, that you shouldn't *also* validate the submitted data at server-side.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in our scenario we will do server side validation too. That y this confusion ! :) . Any Idea how to over ride or using any directive ?

Comment: The key is "server-side validation **too**". If you do prevent invalid forms to be submitted, you'll never get an empty string submitted, unless by a malicious user bypassing your form validation. I don't understand what the problem is. And if you want to perform server-side validation**only**, then don't bother using required, ng-minlength etc. The invalid field will then be populated and submitted as is.